# How to add/sum hours from array in Objective C

Tags: ios

I am new to ios programming and I am stuck on something so simple but cant find answer anywhere ...I need help pls.
I am have a array and it has hours store in it like-
11:30 
13:45
18:00
23:05
How can I add/sum all this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by adding all those hours. What is the expected result when you add those hours?

Comment: Are those "hours" strings in your array?

Comment: Yes they are in String.i want to get a total hour by adding them all .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
NSInteger total = 0;
NSArray *arr = @[@"11:30", @"13:45", @"18:00", @"23:05"];
for (NSString *anHour in arr) {
    NSArray *splitString = [anHour componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSInteger minutes = [splitString[0] integerValue]*60  + [splitString[1] integerValue];
    total += minutes;
}
NSLog(@"Total hours are: %f",total/60.0);
```

Comment: Can you access an object in an array with the "array[1]" syntax? I didn't see that before. Came that together with the @[@"String"] array notation?

Comment: Instead of a float hours, why not do the sum as integer minutes? This will avoid any rounding issues.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks for the suggestion, that would be more accurate. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @SandroMeier, yes you can access array elements that way, and I think those changes were all made at the same time.